# Por que recebo uma pagina em branco ao invés de redirecionar como esta no comando (header: location)?

Tags: php, mysql, post, cookies

Boa noite guys, recentemente fiz um curso de PHP e decidi me aventurar um pouco criando um sistema de login com `$_COOKIE`. Quando eu manualmente defino a variável, consigo validar o login, mas quando passo as informações usando `action="POST"` no formulário, recebo uma página em branco. O formulário html é esse:

```
<form action="/system.php" method="POST">

      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img src="images/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
      </div>


      <label for="usuario"><b>Usuário</b></label>
      <input type="text" name="account_user" required>
      <label for="senha"><b>Senha</b></label>
      <input type="password" name="account_passwd" required>
      <button id="logar" type="submit" class="opcao" style="margin-right: 5px;"><i class="fas fa-user-circle" style="margin-right: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>LOGIN</button>

  </form>
```

A pagina que recebe o formulário `system.php` é essa:

```
$_POST["account_user"];
$_POST["account_passwd"];

//funções que podem ser utilizadas em qualquer parte
include "biblioteca.php";
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//EXIBIR ERROS
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function login_admin(){

    //Verificar dados antes da Query

        $Usuario = $GLOBALS["con"]->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_user='".$_POST['account_user']."' AND account_passwd='".$_POST['account_passwd']."'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($Usuario)>0){

            //Armazenar
            setcookie("account_user", $_POST['account_user']);
            setcookie("account_passwd", $_POST['account_passwd']);
            header('Location: admnistrativo.php');
        }

}
```

Meu arquivo biblioteca.php:

```
    function db_connect(){

    $errocon = "Configura?¡ì??o de Banco de Dados Errada!";
    $errodb = "Banco de Dados Inexistente!";

    $GLOBALS["con"] =  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'empreendedor');
}

//Transforma Query em objeto.
function convert_query_to_json($query){
    $rows = array();
    if($query!=null){
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Caso tudo desse certo, o usuário iria ser redirecionado para `localhost/admnistrativo.php`

Para validar o login, executo

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['account_passwd']) && isset($_COOKIE['account_user'])){
                db_connect();
                $Usuario = $GLOBALS["con"]->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_user='".$_COOKIE['account_user']."' AND account_passwd='".$_COOKIE['account_passwd']."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($Usuario)>0){
                    $Usuario = convert_query_to_json($Usuario)[0];
```

Lembrando que quando defino manualmente o `$_COOKIE`, consigo acessar o sistema, o problema, acredito eu, está na pagina `system.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andre analisando o conteúdo postado dá para ver que faltou você invocar a função `login_admin`. Ela existe mas em nenhum momento é chamada para efetuar a autenticação e criar os cookies em caso de sucesso. Veja os ajustes abaixo, espero que ajude:

```
<%
// Funções que podem ser utilizadas em qualquer parte
include "biblioteca.php";
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// EXIBIR ERROS
/* ... */

// Verificar dados antes da Query
// >>> Atenção com injeção SQL!!! <<<
$Usuario = $GLOBALS["con"]->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_user='".$_POST['account_user']."' AND account_passwd='".$_POST['account_passwd']."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($Usuario) > 0) {
    // Armazenar
    setcookie("account_user", $_POST['account_user']);
    setcookie("account_passwd", $_POST['account_passwd']);
    header('Location: admnistrativo.php');
} else {
    // TODO Enviar o usuário para uma outra página visto
    // que a autenticação falhou
    header('Location: admnistrativo.php'); // >>> Faça seu ajuste aqui <<<
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse arquivo system, você está passando ele inteiro aqui? Porque se for inteiro você está definindo a função login_admin mas não está chamando ela no seu código, por isso se setar o cookie manualmente funciona.
Você também não esta chamando db_connect() antes da consulta em login_admin.

Eu também recomendaria você a não fazer a concatenação do cookie nem do post na sua string de consulta do banco pois isso abre brechas de segurança. O usuário vai conseguir inserir dados não previstos na sua string. 
[Aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) tem um bom exemplo, mas seria basicamente assim:

```
$Usuario = $GLOBALS["con"]->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_user=? AND account_passwd=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_COOKIE['account_user'])
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_COOKIE['account_passwd'])
$stmt->execute
```